# Android studio do not detect nox player as emulator

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

I turn on root on nox player, and enter developer mode in android by click on build number, in developer menu i turned on usb debugging.[use this guide](https://www.bignox.com/blog/how-to-connect-android-studio-with-nox-app-player-for-android-development-and-debug/)
Then go to install folder of bin nox and run command "nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001" and console shows successful message .But no device shows in android studio :(

`adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (36); killing...`
`* daemon started successfully *`
`connected to 127.0.0.1:62001`

I attach 2 picture of android studio situation before and after connect. :)

before connect:
[image]

after connect: it only shows "motorola AOSP on shama" beside no devices!
[image]

What is wrong with my system? how can i debug?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First open Android Studio, open a cmd window and type:
C:\Program Files\Nox\bin>nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:**62001**
In my case appears:

- daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
- daemon started successfully *
  already connected to 127.0.0.1:**62001**

But that don't work, after type:

C:\Program Files\Nox\bin>nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:**5037**

Appears:
connected to 127.0.0.1:**5037**

That connect, for me, Android Studio with Nox emulator.